# Direct limit of iterated automorphism groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, set-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and define a sequence of groups by $G_0=G, G_{i+1}=Aut(G_i)$. Define a homomorphism $f_i:G_i\to G_{i+1}$ by sending each $g\in G_i$ to the automorphism defined by $\varphi_g(x)=g^{-1}xg$. Then take the direct limit of the system
$G_0\to^{f_0} G_1\to^{f_1}...$
in the category of groups.

These are my questions:

- Is the group defined by this construction well defined?
- If it is well defined, is it nontrivial/not interesting? (for example, it is always 0 or always $G$?)

Edit: These two questions provide some interesting information about what the groups $G_i$ could be. [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27861/periodic-automorphism-towers)
[2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-mathrmaut-mathrmaut-mathrmautg-stabilize) . It looks like the sequence very often stabilizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is well defined, and can even be continued past the natural numbers, through the ordinals! And it is very interesting. See e.g. [this paper of Joel David Hamkins](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-11/S0002-9939-98-04797-2/S0002-9939-98-04797-2.pdf), and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151352/iterated-automorphism-groups) at Mathoverflow.

Specifically, you've defined the group $G_\omega$. It has an automorphism group too - that's $G_{\omega+1}$. We can continue this process "transfinitely" - so, $G_\alpha$ is well-defined for every [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\alpha$. The sequence $(G_\alpha: \alpha\in ON)$ is the *automorphism tower* of $G$.

As far as I know, the main question about automorphism towers is when they "terminate" - that is, when (if ever) we hit some $\alpha$ so that $G_\alpha\cong G_{\alpha+1}$ via the canonical map from $G_\alpha$ to $G_{\alpha+1}$. For instance, if $G$ is finite and *centerless* (that is, the only element of $G$ commuting with every other element of $G$), then the automorphism tower terminates after finitely many steps; this was proved by Wielandt. Hamkins' result in the linked paper above is that *every* automorphism tower terminates.

---

As far as I know, continuing research on automorphism problems has a highly set-theoretic flavor.

The *automorphism tower problem* - which is still open - asks about the values of $\tau_\kappa$, the least upper bound on how long automorphism towers of groups of cardinality $<\kappa$ take to terminate. Computing $\tau_\kappa$ - indeed, under *any* reasonable additional axioms! - is extremely hard, and I don't believe has been done. Understanding the map $\kappa\mapsto \tau_\kappa$ is a major open problem.

Another question we can ask is whether we can "change" the height of the automorphism tower of a group via set-theoretic shenanigans (that is, [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics))). Hamkins [has studied this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007299000391), and I believe others (Fuchs?) have as well.

Comment: This is great, thank you. As a follow up, does this still work in the category of topological groups? say let $G$ be finite and give each $G_i$ the discrete topology? (I'm not sure how to define an a topology on $Aut(G)$ in general)

Comment: @Visitor I think the natural thing to look at in the topological case is the *continuous* automorphism group, which can then be given the compact-open topology. I don't believe that this has been looked at.

Comment: In general, anytime you have a way to define a map out of a structure $A$, you can iterate it transfinitely by taking direct limits at limit stages.